# If sendmail fails to resolve smarthost, add to queue rather than fail?

Tags: sendmail, queue

Occasionally, in the middle of the night, DNS fails to resolve our smarthost address. And sendmail decides to send the mail as a "rejected" message. Because "root" is aliased to an off-box address, that also tries to use the smart host, and fails. And then I get a savemail panic.
Is there any way to persuade sendmail that if it can't resolve the smart host, it can queue the message for later?

I have a horrible feeling I just need to get up at 3am and see wtf is going on with the DNS server :-(

Answer (score 1):

**Quick fix** *(temporary?)*:  Use IP address(es) as the smart host.

```
define(`SMART_HOST',`[10.0.0.2]:[10.0.0.2]')dnl
```

Square brackets turn off looking for MX records.

---

Debug procedure suggested:

1. Use `sendmail -d8.20 -bv root` to find out DNS queries asked
2. Make cron execute your test shell script asking the above question every few minutes overnigt